# Graph creation in Java

Tags: java, search, graph, tree, breadth-first-search

What is the best way to construct a undirected graph in java? I need to create a graph so that i could run BFS and DFS on it.The graph should include information such as path cost and adjacent edges.

Answer (score 2):

You can use available libraries. For example, [JgraphT](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht) is a library which provides standard graph algorithms. JgraphT provides an iterator for doing BFS, see [here](http://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/traverse/BreadthFirstIterator.html). Here is an simple example:

```
SimpleWeightedGraph<Integer, DefaultWeightedEdge> graph = new SimpleWeightedGraph<>(DefaultWeightedEdge.class);

graph.addVertex(1);
graph.addVertex(2);
graph.addVertex(3);

DefaultWeightedEdge edge = graph.addEdge(1, 3);
graph.setEdgeWeight(edge, 11.22);

edge = graph.addEdge(3, 2);
graph.setEdgeWeight(edge, 44.33);

BreadthFirstIterator<Integer, DefaultWeightedEdge> it = new BreadthFirstIterator<>(graph);
for (; it.hasNext();) {
    Integer i = it.next();
    System.out.println("Node: " + i);
}
```

Comment: @Schrieveslaach Thanks for the reply, but i want to construct a method on my own rather than using a external library.